# how to fix and remove zero among a number to equalize the digits in an array

Tags: matlab, zero, digits

consider an array in MATLAB :

`a = [102 20 1 30 8 255];`

In this array, I need to make all the numbers to three digits by prefixing zero to all values lie this :

```
a = 102 020 001 030 008 255
```

After that, I need to reverse it again to the same. how can i do this?
I tried to separate the digits and do this. But it failed.

Comment: reverse means the original value of the array a has to be recovered by removing the zero

Comment: _make all the numbers to three digits by prefixing zero_ makes no sense. `20` and `020` _are_ the same number. It's just a displaying matter. To generate _strings_ with leading zeros, try something like `a = [102 20 1 30 8 255]; sprintf('%03i\n', a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [notation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) of [`fprintf`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), which can be saved as a string with [`sprintf`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
>>  a = [102 20 1 30 8 255]

a =

   102    20     1    30     8   255

>> b = sprintf('%.3d ',a)    % b is a single string

b =

102 020 001 030 008 255 

>> a = str2num(b)

a =

   102    20     1    30     8   255
```

Comment: what @luis-mendo said

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert to string. Have a look at the `int2str` or `num2str`functions for example. Then you can easily concatenate zeros at the beginning. For example:

```
s = int2str(10);
['0' s]
```

This gives you `010` as an output.
You can then revert with the `str2num` function.